# Can $f(\Theta)$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^k$, where $\Theta\subset\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Can $f(\Theta)$, the image of $f$ defined as $\{f(\theta),\theta\in\Theta\}$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^k$, where $\Theta\subset\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$? $f$ is a function from $\Theta$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I don't think so, otherwise $f(\Theta)$ would contain a open ball in $\mathbb{R}^k$, which is not possible. Is this correct? If not, can you please give me an example?

Comment: For arbitrary $f \colon \Theta \subset \Bbb R^{k-1} \to \Bbb R^k$? As long as $|\Theta| \geq \mathfrak{c}$ one can define a surjective such $f$, in particular $f(\Theta) = \Bbb R^k$ will be open. Are you interested perhaps in *continuous* $f$ or something of that sort?

Comment: What does $|\Theta|\geq c$, the absolute value of $\Theta$ mean? $f$ can be any function. I cannot think of an example of $f(\Theta)$ is open in the higher dimension than $\Theta$.

Comment: I mean that if $\Theta$ has the same cardinality of $\Bbb R^k$ (which is actually independent of $k$), by definition we can choose a bijection $f \colon \Theta \to \Bbb R^k$ and so $f(\Theta) = \Bbb R^k$ is open. The existence of such a function is not constructive, though, but for arbitrary functions the answer is yes.

Comment: The problem is that an "imaginable" $f$, intuitively speaking, will be differentiable almost anywhere. And in that case you are most likely correct. Although some results of this nature are hard to prove, and I can't come up with a proof right now.

Comment: $\Theta$ can have same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^k$, for example, $\Theta=\mathbb{R}$. I think $f(\mathbb{R})$ cannot be open in $\mathbb{R}^k$, for any $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$, for $k>1$. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: If $f$ is a Lipschitz mapping, i.e. $|f(x)-f(y)| \le C |x-y|$ (unlike the Peano curve example), then this definitely cannot happen by considering the measure of the image $f(\Theta)$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz "This cannot happen" means $f(\Theta)$ cannot be open in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: @Tan: yes, answering the question "can $f(\Theta)$ be open in $\mathbb R^k$..." that is assuming that $\Theta$ is a Borel (or Lebesgue) measurable set. I am not sure what happens if $\Theta$ is not a measurable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [Peano Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve) $\gamma:[0,1]\to Q:=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ where $Q$ is the unit square in the plane. The curve is surjective (the image of the curve is the whole square). Therefore, just pick an open subset $A$ included in the square and set $\Theta:=\gamma^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: The surprising thing about the Peano curve is that it is a *continuous* map that fills space. The example from @zhw. shows that if we don't ask for the map to be somewhat regular, then it is easy to find "nonconstructive" examples

Answer (score 2):

We don't have to get as fancy as a Peano curve. The cardinality of $\mathbb R$ equals the cardinality of  $\mathbb R^k.$ That alone says the answer is yes.

Comment: Why the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^{k}$ means $f(\mathbb{R})$ open in $\mathbb{R}^k$? Does same cardinality spaces always have a bijective mapping?

Comment: @Tan Yes, that’s what it means for two spaces to have the same cardinality

Comment: Your answer was already given in the comments. Then, other questions about regularity were pointed out. Therefore I selected an example that also answers natural further questions.

Comment: @Kosh  Sorry, I didn't read all the comments.